# Suggestions for labels of different kind of doors/gates

Tags: gui-design, terminology

I'm designing a mobile app for home automation.

- Shown at the end of this question is the remote page, which allows the user to control doors and gates.

We have to provide the following three types of gates:

1. Gate for entry for the cars. (Might be garage or just a gate)
2. Smaller gate next to the cars gate for pedestrians.
3. Main entry door to the building/Villa.

   - The following picture shows the car's gate and the pedestrian door.

What should I name these doors and gates in the UI?
Currently I'm doing it like this:
1. Gate
2. Door (Maybe I'll switch to pedestrian gate)
3. (Unable to decide)

[image: Remote page controls][image: Entrance]

Comment: Does it not depend on the house? Should the user not be able to set their own names for their own doors and gates?

Comment: @MattObee.. Currently it is fixed.

Comment: This question is off-topic. There is a SX site for the use of the English language. I am also tempted to say something about the GUI shown — it would be nothing good.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on [English.SE](english.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 3):

Fixed names for variable circumstances is, in itself, fairly bad UX: if you can change that, I suggest you do.

If it's not possible to change, however, I'd just name them after whatever goes through it: "Car" and "Pedestrian" - the user presumably knows what the app is for (opening gates) already, so just needs an identifier

Comment: Sadly, It's not feasible to change the UX at this point. 
The page has controls related to security system as well (top 2 buttons in the circle, see remote page above). So, I believe the identifiers must be more explicit.

Comment: Car / Pedestrian / House ?

Comment: If you have other options, then explicit but still specific options may be best: "Car Gate", "Pedestrian Gate" - and if possible, add a setting to change "Car Gate" to "Garage" when needed (this may also change Pedestrian Gate to just "Gate", depending on your use case)